# Magento 2 checkout required css classes

Tags: magento2, checkout, css, uicomponent

In checkout what's the difference between these css classes on fields:
**required** / **_required** ?

Because I see that some fields have **_required** css class, but the address field block has only **required** (without line character).
And if I send the empty form, the address field block doesn't receives **_error** class (and not receiving the same error design).

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Edit:

This is what the OP is referring to, some classes use `required` and others use `_required`. So what is the difference?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please be a bit more clear as to what your issue is. Are you wanting to have a section of the form required?

Comment: @Rebel I have updated the question with screenshots to show what the OP means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS classnames starting with an underscore are helper classes (e.g. `._active, ._open, ._expanded, ._hidden, ._required`), all other classnames (should) start with a letter. According to the [Magento 2 Developer Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/code-standard-less.html#helper-classes) some parts of the Magento code might not comply with this standard yet and therefore you might still find helper names without an underscore.

> **You must assign HTML helper classes in JavaScript to modify presentation layer.**
>
> HTML helper class names added in JavaScript REQUIRE underscore symbol (`_`) at the beginning and must be written in lowercase.
>
> **Right:** `<div class="tab-element _active">Content</div>`
>
> **Wrong:** `<div class="tab-element active">Content</div>`

Source: [Magento 2 DevDocs / Code demarcation standard](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/code-standard-demarcation.html#you-must-assign-html-helper-classes-in-javascript-to-modify-presentation-layer)